# Function from JS file isn't fired by index.js click evt

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, constructor

I have a function called `handleFileSelect` that's supposed to be triggered from a `change` event in my `index.js` file (as a best practice, all of the events are housed in `index.js`).

When typing `.addEventListener('change',` , the function isn't appearing via intellisense (second param after `'change'`). I believe the issue has to do with how the components are laid out, but I'm not 100% sure.

I took over this project and was not the one who set up the components.

---

**calendar.js :**

```
import axios from "axios";
import XLSX from "xlsx";
import { route } from "silkrouter";

export default class {
  constructor(globalData, mmUser) {
    this.globalData = globalData,
    this.isAdmin = mmUser.IsAdmin,
    this.calendar = null;

  }

    initRoutes() { ... }

    loadEvents(myParam) { ... }

    parseAndUploadFile(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) { 
         // in this block, I'm taking the contents of an uploaded Excel file and parsing it
        }
    } 

    addItemToList(getY, getZ) {

         // in this block, the contents from parseAndUploadFile are added to a list via POST
    }

    handleFileSelect(evt) {
        debugger;
        console.log("handleFileSelect fired") // not reached
        let files = evt.target.files; 

        if (files.length > 0) {
            this.parseAndUploadFile(files[0]);
        }
    }

} // export default class
```

---

**index.js :**

```
import "jquery/dist/jquery.js";
import { router, route } from "silkrouter";
import globalInitProm from "./SiteAssets/scripts/global";
import calendarComponent from "./SiteAssets/scripts/calendar";


let isAdmin;

async function initComponents() {
  isAdmin = await isAdminMember();
  const { globalData, mmUser } = await globalInitProm(isAdmin);

  const calendar = new calendarComponent(globalData, mmUser);
  calendar.initRoutes();

}

initComponents();

/* various click evts are here */


document.getElementById('getFile').addEventListener('change', calendar.handleFileSelect, false); // intellisense can't find handleFS
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<input class="getFile" id="getFile" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Comment: `const calendar` seems to be defined in the scope of the `initComponent` function but you are using it outside where it should not be defined.

Comment: @Stuck so if I'm reading this right, `calendar.handleFileSelect` (or just using `calendar` within the evt) isn't possible, because `calendar` only exists within the scope of `initComponent`? Thanks

Comment: From the code you present it should not be defined. Also the `initComponent` function is `async` which might lead to the calender not being initialized when you try to use it.

Comment: Hey @Stuck. I moved the event to within `initComponent` and it's now firing. If you add your post as an answer, I'll mark it as correct (I won't be able to today, I think there's a two day window or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const calendar` is defined in the scope of the `initComponent` function but you are using it outside where it should not be defined. Move the `...addEventListener(...)` inside the same scope or make the initialized calendar object available to the scope where you want to use it.